# PHP & MySQLi Insert Query Failed

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm having a few issues with MySQLi queries. I have read the docs for PHP several times and have encountered the same error. I am new to MySQLi but have used MySQL.

Here is the error I am receiving after submitting the post data:

> [22-Mar-2014 23:41:17 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /home/ponypwna/public_html/Changelist/cpanel.php on line 32

Here is my code for overviewing:

```
<?php
$MysqlUsername = "*****";
$MysqlPassword = "*****";
$MysqlHostname = "localhost";
$MysqlDatabase = "ponypwna_mane";
/* Establishing Connection here */
$mysqli = new mysqli($MysqlHostname, $MysqlUsername, $MysqlPassword, $MysqlDatabase) or die("Mysql Error: " . $mysqli->error);

//Did we post it?
if (isset($_POST['insertChange'])) {
    #Fetching Post Data
    $change = $_POST['change'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $appliesto = $_POST['appliesto'];
    $progress = $_POST['progress'];
    $completiondate = $_POST['completiondate'];
    $contributor = $_POST['contributor'];

    #Preparing Query
    $insertChange = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO changelist (change, state, appliesto, progress, completiondate, contributor) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $insertChange->bind_param('sssiss', $change, $state, $appliesto, $progress, $completiondate, $contributor);

    #Executing Prepared Query
    $insertChange->execute();

    #Close statement and function
    $insertChange->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: you're not setting `$mysqli` anywhere that I can see...

Comment: Is `$mysqli` variable ever initialized?

Comment: @barell I have set it but for security reasons, I did not include in the post.

Comment: Add it to the code please, but do not include your passwords. There is also another spelling error with your code `$insertChange-close();` there should be `->` not `-`

Comment: The error message implies that either `$mysqli` is not initialised, or the initialisation has failed. Check the code where you're opening the connection and make sure you have some error checking that will tell you what is happening

Comment: Is the $mysqli object created in a function/other class and so its out of scope for this code ?

Comment: @MikeW Thanks for that comment. I mistyped up my MySQLi connection, but I did fix it before your post. I then got another error about bind_params. If you could examine a bit closer that would be helpful.

Comment: @LordNature removed my post. Value binding seems right on second view :) ...

Comment: @LordNature: is your "date string" a valid date format or maybe a localized one?

Comment: @dognose Not sure- My method of getting this data is through a form; this form contains an input with type "date". Would this work or is it invalid for SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are all dumb :)

> Upon second look, I seem to be receiving this error from MySQL
>   (after adding a few debugging tools I was able to see this error): You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'change,
>   state, appliesto, progress, completiondate, contributor) VALUES (?, ?,
>   ?' at line 1

"change" is a reserved keyword in MYSQL. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Add `` arround change (it is a good idea to wrap every column name - there are various reserved keywords):

```
$insertChange = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO changelist (`change`, state, appliesto, progress, completiondate, contributor) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I made this error.

Comment: @LordNature At least, now I know, why my colleague at work is having `t_tables` and `c_columns` :P

Answer (score 0):

**New Answer**
It seems the error is being caused due to an error in your sql syntax.

When you do:

```
$insertChange = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO changelist (change, state, appliesto, progress, completiondate, contributor) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

and when here is an error in the syntax, `$insertChange` is set to false and so it has no method called `bind_param()` as per the [documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#refsect1-mysqli.prepare-returnvalues)

> **Return Values**
>   mysqli_prepare() returns a statement object or FALSE if an error occurred.

---

So a fix would be to copy-past the sql into an phpMyAdmin or whatever and replace the `?` with actual data and run it to see if it works. Maybe one of your columns are missing, spelling error?

Comment: as of the comments: He has instantiated mysqli, just not included it in the code. So the remaining (correct) part of your answer is just a copy of mine :P

Comment: @Krimson I actually added in the definition, but if you read the post. I explain that I did not add it for security reasons. I added the code though for people who passed that up.

Comment: @dognose Excuse me but when I typed up my answer, he didn't have the mysqli initiation... Check the edited section for your self. And no I didn't copy your answer for the last part. its something i noticed my self. Please stop assuming thing. Downvote is only when an answer is not helpfull. Not when you feel competitive and vulnerable

Comment: @Krimson: He mentioned in the comments 3 Minutes before you submitted your post. I'm not feeling competitive. Im just sick of copy/pasting existing answers and/or comments in order to get a "+1". However if you edit your post, i'll remove the "-1". Just can't without another edit.

Comment: @dognose He may have not seen it, but thanks for both your answers. They were helpful.

Comment: @LordNature I have updated my answer, check that out

Comment: @Krimson Either we are on the "same" level, or you are f*** kidding me :P (See my comment(s) on my post) :P

Comment: @dognose I say we are on the same level.

Comment: @Krimson Could accept that :P

Comment: @Krimson Click [here](http://prntscr.com/338s5l) for my table structure.

Comment: Upon second look, I seem to be receiving this error from MySQL (after adding a few debugging tools I was able to see this error): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'change, state, appliesto, progress, completiondate, contributor) VALUES (?, ?, ?' at line 1